# HD60S+ won't pick up sound from my Nintendo Switch

Tags: nintendo-switch

My Elgato HD60S+ won't pickup sound from my Nintendo Switch. I don't have headphones and my settings are right. Can someone please help me?

Comment: How can you be so sure that your settings are right when your sound is not ringing? What do you mean by "I don't have headphones"?

Comment: Most of the websites say unplug headphones out of your Nintendo switch I did that but it still doesn't work

Comment: Could it possibly because of HDCP?

Comment: Is there any way I can fix this? @Skye-AT

Comment: I do not mean to be rude but I've already given a hint (HDCP). If you are so sure about that your settings are being right then you should've already known what that means. I understand your situation but, you know, sometimes Google is faster than our knowledge. That being said, if HDCP is enabled, some games refuses to record audio. Though, if your HD60S+ is not even recording Switch's menu sound then that wouldn't be a culprit. I do not know otherwise, but there's always a possibility of faulty board.